# How to display the List diff with out the common lines in python?

Tags: python

After doing the diff between the two lists, the common lines are being  shown. But My requirement is, when i compare two lists, the common lines should not to be displayed (come in the diff). Can you give some idea how to suppress the same.

```
difflist.py
-----------

import difflib


def main():
  rawfromlines = open('file1.sql', 'r').readlines()
  tolines = open('file2.sql', 'r').readlines()

  list_f1 = []
  list_f2 = []

  for f1 in rawfromlines:
     for part in f1.replace('\n','').split(','):
       list_f1.append(part)

  for f2 in tolines:
     for part in f2.replace('\n','').split(','):
       list_f2.append(part)


  targetfile = open('diff_of_files.sql', 'w')

  differ = difflib.Differ()
  diffs = list(differ.compare(list_f1, list_f2))

  for i in range(0,len(diffs)):
    print diffs[i]

file1.sql
----------

CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
 SALARY int
);
CREATE TABLE JOB1
(
 EMP1 int
);

file2.sql
---------
CREATE TABLE SALARY
(
 EMPNAME VARCHAR2(255)
 SALARY int
);
CREATE TABLE JOB1
(
 EMP1 int
);

Actual Output
---------------
CREATE TABLE SALARY
  (
+  EMPNAME VARCHAR2(255)
   SALARY int
  );
  CREATE TABLE JOB1
  (
   EMP1 int
  );

Expected Output
---------------

CREATE TABLE SALARY
  (
+  EMPNAME VARCHAR2(255)
   SALARY int
  );
```

The common lines are not present.

Comment: use sets instead of lists, sets have native support for operations like difference and intersection. BTW, I think `for i in range(0, len(diffs))` is a code smell in Python, often you want just `for diff in diffs: print diff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Differ` does not have any functionality to print a context like the `HtmlDiff` does. However, you can easily build something like this yourself by keeping a buffer of context lines. Something like this:

```
def print_with_context (diff, context = 3):
    buf = []
    print_more = 0

    for line in diff:
        if line.startswith('-') or line.startswith('+'):
            if len(buf) > context:
                print('...')
            print('\n'.join(buf[-context:]))
            buf = []
            print_more = context
            print(line)
        elif print_more:
            print(line)
            print_more -= 1
            if print_more == 0:
                print('...')
        else:
            buf.append(line)
```

Used like this:

```
print_with_context(differ.compare(list_f1, list_f2), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Rather than print the diff,  I would like to copy the diff output with out common lines in to a separate list. Will this program helps?

Comment: Sure, instead of printing, you can just `yield` them to make this a generator instead and then convert it into a list. Or just collect the printed lines in a list directly.

Comment: Thanks, is there any ways to get the same output using  any diffLib methods?

Comment: I think I answered that in the first sentence of my answer.